# Flask-SQLAlchemy filter on many to many relationship with parent model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Parent model that a couple fo different types of items use as their parent via a foreign key. I also have a many to many relationship on the parent model. I am trying to get the child model based on querying the many to many model.

This is the parent model

```
class MediaItem(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "media_item"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tags', secondary=tags_joiner, backref='media_items')
    videos = db.relationship('Video', backref='Parent', lazy='dynamic')
    audios = db.relationship('Audio', backref='Parent', lazy='dynamic')
    pictures = db.relationship('Picture', backref='Parent', lazy='dynamic')
    codes = db.relationship('Code', backref='Parent', lazy='dynamic')
```

And the many to many relationship

```
class Tags(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)


tags_joiner = db.Table('tags_joiner',
                       db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id')),
                       db.Column('mediaitem_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('media_item.id')),
                       db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('tag_id', 'mediaitem_id'))
```

Finally there is an example fo the child model

```
class Video(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'video'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('media_item.id'))
    file_name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
```

There are a couple of other types of child models as evidenced by the relationships defined in the MediaItem model.

I am looking to do filtering on the child model by the tag. That is to say that given a specific tag, return all the child models that are associated with that tag.

```
Video.query.join(media_tags).filter_by(MediaItem.tags.any(Tags.tag.in_(tag)))
```

Returns that it doesnt know how to connect the three tables, (Could not find a FROM clause to join from. Tried joining to , but got: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'media_item' and 'tags'.)

What could be my approach to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Version-1:** The query below should return the desired result:

```
tag = 'my_filter_tag'
q = (
    db.session
    .query(Video)
    .filter(Video.Parent.has(MediaItem.tags.any(Tags.tag == tag)))
)
```

It might not be the most optimal, as it is produces `SQL` with two nested `EXISTS` clauses, but definitely it is very readable `sqlalchemy` query. Here is the query that is produced for `sqlite`:

```
SELECT  video.id AS video_id, video.parent_id AS video_parent_id, video.file_name AS video_file_name
FROM    video
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    media_item
    WHERE   media_item.id = video.parent_id
        AND (
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM    tags_joiner, tags
            WHERE   media_item.id = tags_joiner.mediaitem_id
                AND tags.id = tags_joiner.tag_id
                AND tags.tag = :tag_1
            )
        )
    )
```

**Version-2:** Somewhat more optimised query would be to join on the `media_item`, but then still perform `exists` on the tag:

```
q = (
    db.session
    .query(Video)
    .join(MediaItem, Video.Parent)
    .filter(MediaItem.tags.any(Tags.tag == tag))
)
```

which will produce the `SQL` as below:

```
SELECT  video.id AS video_id, video.parent_id AS video_parent_id, video.file_name AS video_file_name
FROM    video
JOIN    media_item
    ON  media_item.id = video.parent_id
WHERE   EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    tags_joiner, tags
    WHERE   media_item.id = tags_joiner.mediaitem_id
        AND tags.id = tags_joiner.tag_id
        AND tags.tag = :tag_1
    )
```

You could also join further on `tags_joiner` and `tags` and achieve the result. But this removes some flexibility: if you would like to perform and `OR` check on multiple tags, the result might return multiple `Video` rows, whereas keeping the query with `EXISTS` will take care of that.

---

*Note, that your code has a `media_tags`, but it is not clear what it is.*